# Counting up recursively and using +1 vs ++

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a basic question about recursion and how the difference of +1 and ++ affects the result.

Why is it that this code:

```
var arrayLoop = function(idx){
  if(idx < 5){
    console.log(idx);
     return arrayLoop(idx+1);
   }
};
arrayLoop(0);
```

will work just fine, but this:

```
var arrayLoop = function(idx){
  if(idx < 5){
    console.log(idx);
    return arrayLoop(idx++);
  }
};
arrayLoop(0);
```

results in an infinite loop?

Comment: just adding to the answers, this is why nesting ++ (either before or after) is not a good idea.  It changes idx while you are still using it.  With functional programming (which often uses recursion) the  `idx + 1` is nicer, it doesn't change idx, and expresses the idea of the next in sequence a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example you have used `++` operator as post-increment, so you are using `idx++` and not `++idx`.

What happens is that with post-increment the expression is evaluated with the value before the increment, then it is increment. You can see it like sort of **(mind that's not semantically identical, it's just to give you the idea)**:

```
return arrayLoop(idx);
idx = idx + 1;
```

So you can see that method is always invoked with `0` as argument.

The pre-increment `++idx` operator would invert the operations:

```
idx = idx + 1;
return arrayLoop(idx);
```

Answer (score 2):

i++ is an expression that increments 'i' but returns the value before the increment. You can use ++i to achieve your desired result.